# HDMI TV turns off when I reboot my raspberry 4

Tags: pi-4

My TV turns off when I reboot my raspberry 4, how can I shut down this behaviour ?

Previously, I had RPI 3b+ and this was not happening

The annoying thing is when it reboot, TV doesn t get signal again. I can connect in ssh from my mac, so I can say the pi is up, but I don't get any signal. It seems that TV must be turned on when powering RPI.

EDIT: here is the last part of /var/log/daemon.log

```
Sep 18 22:15:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[117]: Inserted module 'i2c_dev'
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi fake-hwclock[115]: Wed Sep 18 20:16:16 UTC 2019
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[127]: e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[127]: rootfs: clean, 159860/7539840 files, 2452021/31193088 blocks
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Create System Users.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 163 (plymouthd).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[169]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device /dev/serial1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0c25ed9c-01.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in FUSE Control File System being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0c25ed9c-01...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[166]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[168]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[170]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[184]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[159]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[176]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[313]: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[313]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 301 files, 81962/516191 clusters
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device Crucial_CT250MX200SSD1 1.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0c25ed9c-01.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device TOSHIBA_DT01ACA200 HDD.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounting /home/pi/hdd...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounting /home/pi/ssd...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounted /home/pi/ssd.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi ntfs-3g[336]: Version 2017.3.23AR.3 integrated FUSE 28
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi ntfs-3g[336]: Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "HDD", NTFS 3.1)
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi ntfs-3g[336]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi ntfs-3g[336]: Mount options: nosuid,nodev,user,exec,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,rw,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi ntfs-3g[336]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounted /home/pi/hdd.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Preprocess NFS configuration...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Set console font and keymap.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nfs-config.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Preprocess NFS configuration.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plymouth-read-write.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 163 (plymouthd).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS server being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS client and server being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target NFS client services.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on triggerhappy.socket.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily rotation of log files.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily man-db regeneration.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting rng-tools.service...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Turn on SSH if /boot/ssh is present being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting triggerhappy global hotkey daemon...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Copy user wpa_supplicant.conf being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi rng-tools[397]: Starting Hardware RNG entropy gatherer daemon: rngd.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi rngd[403]: rngd 2-unofficial-mt.14 starting up...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi alsactl[402]: alsactl 1.1.8 daemon started
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi thd[401]: Found socket passed from systemd
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed)...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi rngd[403]: entropy feed to the kernel ready
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[411]: dev: loaded udev
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Check for v3d driver...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[411]: forked to background, child pid 444
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started triggerhappy global hotkey daemon.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started rng-tools.service.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 108) and group 'avahi' (GID 113).
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up.
Sep 18 22:16:22 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[399]: want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[479]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Successfully called chroot().
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[435]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Server startup complete. Host name is raspberrypi.local. Local service cookie is 546310688.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Check for v3d driver.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: minidlna server...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Plex Media Server...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in fast remote file copy program daemon being skipped.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[427]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkit.service' requested by ':1.5' (uid=0 pid=422 comm="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd ")
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Plex Media Server.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Permit User Sessions.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi polkitd[506]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[427]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 163 (plymouthd).
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 163 (plymouthd).
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plymouth-quit-wait.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Sep 18 22:16:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 22:16:24 raspberrypi raspi-config[414]: Checking if shift key is held down: No. Switching to ondemand scaling governor.
Sep 18 22:16:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed).
Sep 18 22:16:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Sep 18 22:16:25 raspberrypi minidlna[484]: [2019/09/18 22:16:25] minidlna.c:631: error: Media directory "V,/home/pi/Vidéos/" not accessible [No such file or directory]
Sep 18 22:16:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: minidlna server.
Sep 18 22:16:27 raspberrypi lightdm[512]: crtc 0: disable
Sep 18 22:16:27 raspberrypi lightdm[512]: screen 0: 1920x1080 507x285 mm  96.08dpi
Sep 18 22:16:27 raspberrypi lightdm[512]: crtc 0:    1920x1080  60.00 +0+0 "HDMI-1"
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Reached target Paths.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Reached target Timers.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c1 of user pi.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Reached target Default.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Startup finished in 224ms.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi lightdm[512]: Error opening audit socket: Protocol not supported
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: carrier acquired
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: DUID 00:01:00:01:24:b7:ed:78:dc:a6:32:16:6e:32
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: IAID 32:16:6e:31
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: adding address fe80::4a34:599c:bb6e:418a
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::4a34:599c:bb6e:418a.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 18 22:16:28 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Registering new address record for fe80::4a34:599c:bb6e:418a on eth0.*.
Sep 18 22:16:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user pi.
Sep 18 22:16:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.0.22
Sep 18 22:16:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[444]: eth0: probing address 192.168.0.22/24
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi btuart[412]: bcm43xx_init
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi btuart[412]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi btuart[412]: Set Controller UART speed to 3000000 bit/s
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi btuart[412]: Device setup complete
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice system-bthelper.slice.
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=1000 pid=606 comm="/usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e LXDE ")
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Sep 18 22:16:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Starting SDP server
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started BluezALSA proxy.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bthelper[705]: Can't init device hci0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill (132)
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bthelper@hci0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bthelper@hci0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[427]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=690 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi bluetoothd[690]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.15 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[427]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=723 comm="pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi ")
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=723 comm="pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi ")
Sep 18 22:16:31 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=723 comm="pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi ")
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi systemd[592]: Started Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Sep 18 22:16:32 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[615]: [session uid=1000 pid=615] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=723 comm="pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi ")
```

Comment: Please provide more details, as your question seems rather vague/broad, unrelated to the Pi, as it stands. What do your logs say happens at reboot, and how is the TV powered? Maybe the TV goes into standby when there is no video signal (while the PI reboots). In which case, that would be an issue with the TV settings, and nothing to do with the Pi itself.

Comment: are the TV and the RPi in the same room?

Comment: @Greenonline you re right, I did it too quickly, but I had no clue what to check. I will check the reboot log.

Comment: @jsotola yes, tv and RPI is connected via HDMI in the same room

Comment: It won't help with the turning off on reboot problem, but adding `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` to `/boot/config.txt` should fix the no signal when TV was off problem. @jsotola I so wanted to ask that...

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for the trick, it worked